How can implement a UI/UX pre-populated info (as PPT or doc) with editable and download functionality in react project?
I am working on a react project where I have to implement this functionality but Not aware which approach be best and how can implement it.
As a user, when I click on ‘Create my business plan’ (or pitch deck, one one-page business plan) a pre-populated document with all their business information should appear below.
Please recommend 1 solution showing how a user could edit a business plan or pitch deck, then can export.

Option 1: Google Docs. For example, is it easiest to embed a Google Docs API? If it is Google Docs - what would a user be required to do? Do they need to sign up with google? Would it take them away from our site?

Option 2: Online viewer + Microsoft word/PDF download?

Option 3:  Editable boxes like (Similar to Live Plan do) with an export option that compiles the information


Please also recommend how this could be exported from the site as a PDF and an editable document.
As of now in my mind is (after looking live plan example)
If I create UI/UX for all the pages (e.g. PPT) and will provide the editable functionality on every page.
How will show every slide page on UI?
We can show the pages one by one means using these buttons backwards and forward< >
Users can change the pages and will give the feel of a PPT.
Regarding download?

I am looking for the libraries that we can use to download the pages in PPT or PDF format.
I am not fully sure about my solution it will be good or not? So please suggest the right solution.

